# Mark associative function as strict in Haskell to avoid space leaks

Tags: haskell, ghc

For long time, I had difficulty in understanding why "simple" folds cause space leaks in Haskell. This [article](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2538488) is very helpful, but in a surprising way.

I'll briefly quote the example of `foldr` applied to `+` which evaluates like this:

```
1 + (2 + sum1 [3..n])
```

Instead of:

```
(1 + 2) + sum1 [3..n]
```

As the comment suggests, even this isn't strict enough to run in constant space.

This looks like the "obvious" thing compiler should do when function is known to be strict and associative. Should rewrite rules be used for this purpose? It's the only option I'm aware of (other than rewriting each instance manually).

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re going for here. Your parentheses are wrong, that’s foldr not foldl. The issue also isn’t really in any way about commutativity, foldl already looks like what you’d want to rewrite it to, it still isn’t strict though.

Comment: In addition to Cubic's remarks, I believe you mean "associative" rather than "commutative".

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question.

Comment: Note that in floating-point arithmetic, operations like `+` or `*` are [not actually associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Nonassociativity_of_floating_point_calculation); due to rounding errors, you can get very different results when using `foldr` vs `foldl` on the same list of numbers.

Comment: If the operation is known to be strict and associative, why not just use `foldl'` anyway? The Prelude provides that function for this exact reason.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - to be pedantic, `foldl'` is not in Prelude, only in `Data.List` (agreed on always using that over `foldl` though)

Comment: `foldr` won't run in constant space because it is not tail recursive, that strictness won't save you at all